# C# call interface method within class

Tags: c#, class, interface, call

```
interface ILol
{
   void LOL();
}

class Rofl : ILol
{
   void ILol.LOL()
   {
      GlobalLOLHandler.RaiseROFLCOPTER(this);
   }
   public Rofl()
   {
      //Is there shorter way of writing this or i is there "other" problem with implementation??
      (this as ILol).LOL();
   }
}
```

Comment: Try avoiding to call "virtual" functions from a constructor! You may end up calling an implementation which accesses a not entirely constructed object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've implemented the interface [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) which, in general, you don't need to do.  Instead, just implement it implicitly and call it as you would any other method:

```
class Rofl : ILol
{
    public void LOL() { ... }

    public Rofl()
    {
        LOL();
    }
}
```

(Note your implementation will also need to be public.)

Comment: You realize your code example implement it explicitly still, right? :)

Comment: What is difference between implicit and explicit implementation? If i dont add ILol. before LOL, then compiler complains that there is no implimentation of ILol.LOL.

Comment: Explicit interfaces can only be called when the object is cast to the interface type.  There are various obscure advantages to this, but otherwise you should avoid it.  As for why your code isn't working, I can only guess: are the methods that implement your interface publicly accessible?

Comment: To clarify:  what ladenedge is saying in the comment immediately above, is that OP needed to add `public` in front of his declaration, when he took away `ILol.`.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `as`, just cast:

```
((ILol)this).LOL();
```

Answer (score 9):

You may want to change the cast from `(this as ILol)` to `((ILol)this)`. An as cast is allowed to return null, which could cause confusing errors later and which the compiler has to test for.

Comment: Come again?  What's wrong with the `as` cast, versus the non-`as`?

Comment: Using the object returned from `as` before checking for null is a bad practice.  The code above won't exhibit any problems as written, but won't be as resilient during refactoring.

Comment: The as cast can return null, so the compiler needs to test for null before calling the method so it can generate the null reference exception. a regular cast can't ever return null so the compiler can elide the test for null.

Comment: The above discussion might confuse someone who recently learned to use `as`, so they can handle situations where an object can't be cast to the target type. The rule is: if you aren't 100% certain that the cast will always be valid, use `as`, then **test** whether the result is `null`. If it can't possibly fail [here, we know `this` is an `ILol`, because it is defined to be], then do the direct cast, `(ILol)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

public class Entry{
      public static void Main(){
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.DoWork();
    }
}

interface IDemo1{
    void DoWork();
}

interface IDemo2{
    void DoWork();
}

public class MyClass : IDemo1, IDemo2{
    
    public void DoWork(){
        Console.WriteLine("Class Do work");
        
        if(true){ // as per any condition
               ((IDemo1)this).DoWork();
        }else{
            ((IDemo2)this).DoWork();
        }
    }
  
    void IDemo1.DoWork(){
         Console.WriteLine("Demo 1 Do work");
    }
    
    void IDemo2.DoWork(){
         Console.WriteLine("Demo 2 Do work");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No not if you are explicitly implementing the interface. If you make it implicit by removing the interface name from the implemented method it'll work as you want.

```
void LOL()
{
    GlobalLOLHandler.RaiseROFLCOPTER(this);
}
public Rofl()
{
    LOL();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to cast at all. Since `ROFL` implements `ILOL` you can simply call `this.LOL()` or even just `LOL();`

Comment: -1 Wrong. ROFL explicitly implements `ILOL` and cannot access `ILOL` members without having access to an instance (`this` casted) of `ILOL`.